# Github get labels of PULL request from api

Tags: javascript, github-api

I use the [Github API](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/) to get my open pull requests. Now I also want to add the labels attached to my view. How can I get them?

Thats the URL I use got GET the data so far:

> url = 'https://api.github.com/repos/' + name_repository + '/pulls?access_token=' + TOKEN;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To fetch the labels for a pull request, you need to fetch the associated issue (pull requests are basically issues with code attached). So, if you have pull request `324` in repository `foo/bar`, then fetch this issue to get the labels for that pull request:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/foo/bar/issues/324
```

See https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#labels-assignees-and-milestones

The same thing is true if you want to fetch a list of pull request -- you need to fetch the list of issues and use the labels from that.

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck with getting labels of a PR and the marked answer wasn't very relevant for my usecase:

### Using GH GraphQl

```
gh api graphql -F OWNER=$OWNER -F REPO_NAME=$REPO_NAME -F PULL_REQUEST_NUMBER=$PULL_REQUEST_NUMBER -f query='
  query ($OWNER: String!, $REPO_NAME: String!, $PULL_REQUEST_NUMBER: Int!) {
    repository(owner: $OWNER, name: $REPO_NAME) {
      pullRequest(number: $PULL_REQUEST_NUMBER) {
        labels(first: 100) {
          edges {
            node {
              name
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }' --jq '.data.repository.pullRequest.labels.edges.[].node.name'
```

### Using GH CLI

```
gh api repos/$OWNER/$REPO_NAME/pulls/$PULL_REQUEST_NUMBER --jq '.labels.[].name'
```

### Inside a GH workflow

You can get the latest labels added just on the PR (not issues) by using GH APIs: (write permissions are needed)

```
name: Get Labels
on: [pull_request]
permissions:
  pull-requests: write
jobs:
  get-labels:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: |
          labels="$(gh api repos/$OWNER/$REPO_NAME/pulls/$PULL_REQUEST_NUMBER --jq '.labels.[].name')"
          echo "$labels"
        shell: bash
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          OWNER: ${{ github.repository_owner }}
          REPO_NAME: ${{ github.event.repository.name }}
          PULL_REQUEST_NUMBER: ${{ github.event.pull_request.number }}
```

If you're using a workflow, you might be better off by using below, but it caches the labels from the time of PR creation. So, unless you close/re-open the PR or open a new PR, labels won't change:

```
github.event.pull_request.labels.*.name
```